# How to control fungal infection on Moringa

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, seedlings, fungus, tropical

7 week old moringa grown from seed started exhibiting white spots and yellowing on leaves. The bottom ones died and dropped off, although new growth continues.

Reading that it could be a nutrient deficiency, I have added some magnesium chloride solution, as well as molases and a mix of kelp and microbial inoculate (several species bacteria plus micchorizal fungi) a few days ago to ensure optimum nutrition for the plants.

On the other hand I also read it might be a ph imbalance, the ph of my tap water has not been verified yet but none of the other plants seem to have had a problem with it up to now.

[image: sick moringa]

I also put them onto a capillary mat and moved them into a less sunny spot so there is no more overhead watering. They (together with all the other potted plants) were wilting daily by the late afternoon, even though there was only exposure to a few hours of intense sunlight (Southern Spain, summer temperatures are running at 30 - 40 C now) and these measures have successfully stopped the wilting.

Some of the surrounding plants recently began to exhibit similar discoloration, such as papaya and pigeon pea seedlings which are also less than 2 months old, whereas such as buckwheat do not.

Any help identifying the problem and possible solutions would be most appreciated.